# How to import PostGIS layer with geography type to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I tried to import in QGIS a layer from a PostgreSQL table with a geography type column created through the extension PostGIS.

I noticed that QGIS doesn't seem to like the geography column...

Here the step to create the column...

`ALTER TABLE traffico ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT,4326);`

then to update the column...

`UPDATE traffico SET geog = ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')');`

but then when I connect QGIS to my server I see this:

[image: Import PostGIS layer to QGIS]

There's no way I can find to tell QGIS to treat my column as a geography type instead of geometry type. Indeed if I try to upload the layer like this the point coordinates do not correspond to reality.

Comment: Please go though following links which contains (difference between Geography and the geometry data type ,when to use this type) http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ch04.html#PostGIS_Geography ,http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/postgis-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-geography-and-geometry-types

Comment: Based on the comments to this question, it seems like it's possible if you use the template to create your PostGIS database
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142954/postgis-geography-data-type-not-displaying-in-qgis?rq=1