# Purpose of geography_columns and geometry_columns views in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type, sql-view, geometry-data-type

Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of `geography_columns` view and `geometry_columns` view in a PostGIS database?

My `geography_columns` view is empty so I can't see what the purpose of it is.

Comment: Please see this Question and Accepted answer - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/postgis-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-geography-and-geometry-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`geometry_columns`  is part of the [Simple Features specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features) for [OGC](https://www.ogc.org/standard/sfs/) and [ISO 19125-2:2004](https://www.iso.org/standard/40115.html) Standards compliance. `geography_columns` is a non-Standard variation to support the `geography` type.

Answer (score 4):

Those views (tables in older versions) is there to help client software fast understand what it can expect of the datasets. Most of the information in those views is also in each geometry, like srid, number of dimensions and so on. But it would take a very long time for a client program to scan all the geometries to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

In a perhaps simplified explanation:

> ... geometry_columns is used by certain applications to be aware of which tables in the database contain geometry data.  [QGIS Training Manual 17: Spatial Database Concepts with PostGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/simple_feature_model.html#:%7E:text=Why%3F%20geometry_columns%20is%20used%20by%20certain%20applications%20to%20be%20aware%20of%20which%20tables%20in%20the%20database%20contain%20geometry%20data.)

In PostGIS, geometry_columns and geography_columns are system views that serve the purpose of providing metadata to correctly interpret and manipulate "spatial data" stored in  within a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

The following is from the PostGIS Manual [4.6.2. GEOMETRY_COLUMNS View](https://postgis.net/docs/en/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#geometry_columns)

> In PostGIS geometry_columns is a view reading from database system catalog tables. This ensures that the spatial metadata information is always consistent with the currently defined tables and views. The view structure is: \d geometry_columns

Which includes the following columns: f_table_catalog, f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column,  coord_dimension, srid, and type.