# Dropped geometry_columns and geography_columns tables

Tags: postgis

(cross-posted from SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/55869582/2802810)

I've accidentally dropped geometry_columns and geography_columns tables from an existing PostgreSQL PostGIS database schema - let's call it mydb.myschema.

[This post](https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2012/12/04/spatial_ref_sys-and-geometry_columns/) outlines how to restore using CREATE TABLE ... with .sql from PostGIS install (I am on a shared server and am having to get my devops to look for them because of permissions).

I wanted to check if this will work. Also, do these two tables (geometry_columns and geography_columns) contain data relating to the geometries held in existing tables in mydb.myschema. Or do geometry_columns and geography_columns hold reference information for spatial operations?

Any advice from anyone who has gone through this before?

Running PostGIS 2.5.2 on PG 11.x.

[NOTE: No backup available as snapshots weren't set up beforehand...]

Comment: Found SQL on my server to re-generate these two as VIEWS. So the tables hold information about geometry as per OGC Simple Features specification see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54849/104667. Is there anything I've missed though I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you linked to is outdated; nowadays, `geomtry_columns` and `geography_columns` are views that automatically extract their data from the Postgres system tables.

You should be able to find the `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statements in the file `share/contrib/postgis-x.x/postgis.sql` in your Postgres installation.