# CartoDB's SQL API: Row too large

Tags: postgis, carto, sql

I am trying to run the following PostGIS query using CartoDB's SQL API:

```
SELECT 
the_geom,
ST_Area(ST_Intersection(the_geom::geography,ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-52.4379, -12.6235),4326)::geography, 25000))) / 1000000 AS polyarea FROM 
    dataset1
WHERE
    ST_Intersects(the_geom::geography,ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-52.4379, -12.6235),4326)::geography, 25000))
```

The same query works with two other datasets (one of which has 735,000 rows), but returns a

> "row too large error"

for this particular dataset (which "only" has 160,400 rows).

**Update:** Is it possible that the features are too complex for the calculations?

Comment: You are buffering a geography datatype, ie, lat/lon, by 25000 degrees? That might be part of your problem. OK, I take it back, in psql such a query works, though it strikes me an non-sensical to have anything beyond (-180,180) and (-90,90).

Comment: The casting to geography is what actually allows me to use meters instead of degrees (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types).

Comment: so it is, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was fixed by removing the format parameter, so the SQL query itself actually wasn't at fault here (username.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?**format=GeoJSON**&q=SELECT...).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the geometries are too large in terms of vertices, which will result in a very long WKB value that would need to be returned by the SQL API. If you don't need a high precision for them you could use [ST_Simplify_PreserveTopology](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html) in order to reduce a little bit the length of the geometries.