# Finding closest segment to a point using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, proximity

I am trying to find the closest road segment to a point that I have and return an attribute from the closest segment to the given points.

I know in PostGIS I need to use ST_ClosestPoint, St_distance and min functions, but I keep having syntax errors.

So far my code looks like

```
WITH closest_segment As
)
 SELECT
  ST_ClosestPoint(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-122.206111 47.983056)')::GEOMETRY,   
    shape::GEOMETRY)AS segment_location  --shape is the geography WKB    

 FROM
  public.road_segments
)
 RETURNING closest_segment
WITH new_segment AS
)
 SELECT 
  MiN(ST_Distance(closest_segment::GEOM,ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-122.206111 
   47.983056)')::GEOMETRY) 
 FROM 
  closest_segment
)
 RETURNING closest_segment
```

My knowledge of PostGIS and coding in it is very limited.

Comment: Why are creating a geography and then casting it to a geometry?
`ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-122.206111 47.983056)')::GEOMETRY`
What SRID is your data in?
See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `road_segments` table have *geographies* written in `geog` column you can try this query:

```
SELECT
    geog,
    dist
FROM
    (SELECT
        rs.geog,
        ST_Distance(rs.geog, ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-122.206111 47.983056)'), false) AS dist
    FROM
        public.road_segments AS rs) AS roads_with_distances
ORDER BY
    dist
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are searching for the closest line *edge* to your point, you can do a K-Nearest Neighbour (KNN, or 1NN in this case), based on [this answer](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_box.html). However you want to use the [<#> operator](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_box.html) instead, since that operates on the edges of the bounding boxes, rather than the centroids.

```
SELECT *
FROM public.road_segments r
ORDER BY r.geom <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.206111 47.983056)')
LIMIT 1;
```