# Choosing datatype for holding Latitude, Longitude and Altitude in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, latitude-longitude, altitude

I'm trying to take advantage of the many functions available in Postgis for dealing with latitude and longitude coordinate systems.
However, I would like to add some altitude information to my database and I can't find the proper answer for which datatype should be used for properly holding Latitude, Longitude and Altitude in Postgis?

I have found that Geometry type is capable of X, Y and Z, but the Geography type only holds Latitude and Longitude.
Is there and differences between both?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types

Comment: Any special geometry kind?
Should it be human-readable?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why geography can't hold Z. Did you try it?

As per the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography):

`CREATE TABLE testgeog(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, the_geog geography(POINTZ,4326) );`

Answer (score 0):

For geometries, like `PointZ` which can store Z values, you can try the WKB or WKT formats for example.
WKB is particularly well suited for database.
Transformations are easily performed as it is an OGC standard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text
http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-063r5/12-063r5.html

Comment: I would highly recommend using the postgis geometry/geography types instead of using WKB or WKT. The performance will be much better and the use of postgis functions will be a lot easier (and faster).